# How to replace part of string with regular expression in Visual Basic

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need to replace part of strings, one is a **RGBA** and the other is a **RGB**, both from a CSS style-sheet on **Textbox** in Visual Basic.

The thing is a little more complicated, the alpha value varies and sometimes it has spaces, I guess regex is the better way to do it, but I don't know how, let me put some examples:

```
// RGBA
rgba(15,90,110,0.4);
rgba(15, 90,110, 0.2);
rgba(15, 90, 110, 0.35);
rgba(15, 90, 110,0.14);
rgba(15,90, 110,0.1) !important;
rgba(15,90, 110, 0.1);

// RGB
rgb(21, 25, 140);
rgb(21,25, 140);
rgb(21, 25,140);
rgb(21,25,140);
rgb(21, 25,140) !important;

// And so on...
```

What I'm using to replace it is the `Replace` function from Visual Basic:

```
' RGBA
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("rgba(15,90,110,0.35)", "rgba(40,133,183,0.35)")

' RGB
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("rgb(21,25,140)", "rgb(40,175,81)")
```

The problem comes when the alpha value changes or when it has spaces...
For the RGB I replace each spacing option, but I have to do it with different colors, and the code gets too long (4 lines of code per color), is there a way to do it with regex too?

Note: I don't replace it including `;` because sometimes it has the *important* flag, so that way I'll keep it as it is, by the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Can somebody help me out, please? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
Private Function ReplaceRGBValue(ByVal i_sReplaceText As String, ByVal i_sOldRGBValue As String, ByVal i_sNewRGBValue As String) As String
    Dim sR As String = i_sOldRGBValue.Split(",")(0)
    Dim sG As String = i_sOldRGBValue.Split(",")(1)
    Dim sB As String = i_sOldRGBValue.Split(",")(2)
    Dim sPattern As String = "((?:rgba|rgb|RGBA|RGB)[ ]*\([ ]*)([ ]*" & sR & "[ ]*,[ ]*" & sG & "[ ]*,[ ]*" & sB & "[ ]*)(,[0-9 \.]+\)|\))"
    Dim sReplacement As String = "${1}" & i_sNewRGBValue & "${3}"
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(i_sReplaceText, sPattern, sReplacement)
End Function
```

The regex is:

`(?:rgba|rgb|RGBA|RGB)[ ]*\([ ]*` - Match either upper or lower case rgb or rgba, followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by open paren (escaped), followed by 0 or more spaces.

`[ ]*" & sR & "[ ]*,[ ]*" & sG & "[ ]*,[ ]*" & sB & "[ ]*` - Match numbers with 0 or more spaces separated by commas

`(,[0-9 \.]+\)|\))` - Match a comma followed by a number, decimal point or space, or just a close paren (escaped).

The extra parentheses are capture groups that you can substitute back into the String with `${1}` and `${3}` in the `sReplacement`.

Use this function like this:

```
Dim sResult As String = ReplaceRGBValue("rgba(15,90,110,0.35)", "15,90,110", "40,133,183")
```

EDIT: To do the replacements in batch, try putting this function in a for loop like this:

```
  Private Sub BatchUpdate()
        ' Add more find/replace values to this array like {{"find,this,value","replace,with,this"}, _
        '                                                  {"also,find,this","and,replace,again"},...}
        Dim sReplacements(,) As String = {{"15,90,110", "40,133,183"}, _
                                          {"21,25,140", "40,175,81"}}
        Dim sResult As String = TextBox1.Text
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(sReplacements)
            sResult = ReplaceRGBValue(sResult, sReplacements(i, 0), sReplacements(i, 1))
        Next
        TextBox2.Text = sResult
    End Sub
```

I hope that works.

Comment: Edited so it mimics more closely the behavior in OP.

Comment: Hi, it might work for manual work, the text I have is from a CSS style-sheet on Textbox, it has a lot more strings, and about 4000 lines of styles... is it possible to make the function to find the strings on the text automatically? Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Using your example code, would `TextBox2.Text = ReplaceRGBValue(TextBox1.Text, "15,90,110", "40,133,183")` work?

Comment: Hi, no, it doesn't work, the text on TextBox1 is a CSS style-sheet with about 4000 lines

Comment: Hi, I'd like to help, but I'm not sure I understand the additional requirement.  I don't think I'm understanding the significance of the 4000 lines.  The code I've shown will do a global find and replace on any number of lines.  Are you trying to automate the find/replace values?  Where will those values come from?  Can you add more to your question?

Comment: Hi, take a look at this for example _(the stylesheet from this stie)_ here is the link: `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e2cbb1956798` it has it's colors all arond the styles, like: `rgba(255,255,255,0.9)` or `rgba(239,240,241,0.75)` and so on... Well, my style-sheet is similar to this one, has a lot more text styles and the parts where the code has spaces or not _(this example has no spaces because the code has been compressed, mine is not compressed, sometimes has spaces sometimes times not_, I tried your code, but it does not make any replacement.

Comment: Are you trying to replace all the RGB's in the file with one value, or do a find and replace like your example?  The following code absolutely works to replace a single value in that CSS file: `TextBox2.Text = ReplaceRGBValue(TextBox1.Text, "239,240,241", "40,133,183")`  This replaces the value `rgba(239,240,241,0.75)` with `rgba(40,133,183,0.75)`.

Comment: Hi, in my example, I do it manually, because I can't find a way to make it automatically, but the idea is to make a function (like yours) that allows me to enter the old values (the ones to search) and the new values (the ones to replace with), with RGB I use 4 lines of code per color (I did it manually with each combination of the spacing), the idea, is to be able to do it automatically, whether are RGB or RGBA and replace the old values with the new ones without having to do it manually, and because of the spaces, it makes it more difficult to search and replace...

Comment: I've added an edit to do the replacements in batch.  I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Just a note that this function will handle spaces in the text to replace.  The code in the answer replaces all your examples.

Comment: Awesome, it works, thanks a lot, that really helps... thanks!!